# How to call the chairs whose back will bend backwards when you rest against it?

Tags: word-request, nouns, terminology

I am sorry if my description is not clear enough. You know there are certain office chairs (unless the wooden chairs or steel folded chair) whose back can bend backwards when you lean against them. Is there a special term for this feature? How to call such chairs?

Comment: Reclining chairs or recliners?

Comment: You wouldn't find an office chair being called  a *recliner*. The generic term is more likely an *executive* or *ergonomic* chair, one that has an *adjustable* back. But I'm not giving this as an actual answer because I'm not totally confident that there isn't a better term.

Comment: [The term *tilt-back chairs* is used sometimes](http://www.smithbrothersfurniture.com/catalog/ctl/search/mid/580/a/11/c/sh), but it doesn't seem to refer to office chairs.

Comment: Other possible terms that get some hits are "flex[ible] back", "flexback", "tension[ed] back", "springback", or "spring-loaded back", but I don't see an industry standard term.

Answer (score 2):

A ***recliner*** generally refers to an armchair (or sofa or couch) that can recline, and often has a footrest that lifts up as the back goes back.

However, a ***reclining office chair*** is an office chair that allows the person sitting in it to lean back, and have the backrest lean back with them.

These are generally high end office chairs, and may be called ***executive*** chairs, but not all executive chairs have that feature.